# How can I get a data from specific text in div class using a BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just developing **Scraper** with the python.
I want to scrape some text in homepage, and I wrote the code in like this to get the specific test data, but it returns nothing.

This is the part of the html where I want to scape

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" id="ui-id-94" aria-labelledby="ui-id-93" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; height: 210px;">
<p>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/PBDCIS">Computer and Information Systems (Post-Baccalaureate Diploma)</a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/DPCSTI">Computing Studies and Information Systems (Diploma)</a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/PDDATA">Data Analytics (Post-Degree Diploma)</a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/ACTCSI_DA">Data and Analytics</a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/PDEMTC">Emerging Technology (Post-Degree Diploma)</a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/PDICT">Information and Communication Technology (Post-Degree Diploma) </a>
    <a href="/programs-courses/catalogue/programs/ACTCSI_WEB">Web and Mobile Computing</a>
</p>
```

I want to get the program names, I code like this but it returns an empty list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import re
import sys

URL = "https://www.douglascollege.ca/programs-courses/catalogue/programs"

    r = requests.get(URL, headers = self.requestHeaders())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    test = soup.find_all("a", class_='ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active')

    print(test)
```

what is the problem...?

Comment: first problem: it seems this page uses JavaScript to add these elements but `requests`, `Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run JavaScript. OR you my try to find url used by JavaScript to get data from server and then use this url with `requests` - maybe you get data as JSON string and then you will no need `Beautifulsoup`.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `soup.find_all()` searches for "a" elements with the classes ui-accordion-content, ui-helper-reset, etc but none of those "a" elements have those classes. Try removing the class part.

Comment: good idea but problem is bigger - this page uses JavaScript to add these elements.

Comment: furas comment is correct, stripping out the class ID won't do the trick because there are no <a> tags in the soup.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: this page uses JavaScript and `requests`, `Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. And it can gives you full HTML which you can search with `Selenium` or use with `Beautifulsoup`

Second problem: you have to search `div` with these classes and later inside `div` you have to search `a` whithout these classes.

---

BTW: to control browser you will have also driver for [Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/) or [Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

---

Code:

```
import selenium.webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.douglascollege.ca/programs-courses/catalogue/programs"

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

all_div = soup.find_all("div", class_='ui-accordion-content')

for div in all_div:
    all_items = div.find_all("a")

    for item in all_items:
        print(item.text)
```

Part of result:

```
Basic Occupational Education - Electronics and General Assembly
Basic Occupational Education - Food Services
Basic Occupational Education - Retail and Business Services
Child and Youth Care (Bachelor of Arts)
Child and Youth Care (Diploma)

Classroom and Community Support (Certificate)
Classroom and Community Support (Diploma)
Education Assistance and Inclusion (Certificate)
Early Childhood Education (Certificate)
Early Childhood Education (Diploma) 
Early Childhood Education: Infant/Toddler (Post-Basic Certificate)
Early Childhood Education: Special Needs - Inclusive Practices (Post-Basic Certificate)
Employment Supports Specialty
Therapeutic Recreation (Bachelor)
Therapeutic Recreation (Diploma)
Accounting (Bachelor of Business Administration)
Accounting (Certificate)
```

---

**EDIT:** The same without `BeautifulSoup` using only `Selenium`

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = "https://www.douglascollege.ca/programs-courses/catalogue/programs"

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

all_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ui-accordion-content")]')

for div in all_div:
    all_items = div.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

    for item in all_items:
        print(item.get_attribute('textContent'))
        #print(item.text) # doesn't work for hidden element
```

Comment: Thank you for ur comment :) I could learn from you that bs4 does not work on the JavaScript! Thank you!

Comment: I add the libraries what I need, such as `selenium` and `webdriver_manager.chrome` for specify the web driver.Chrome(), litk this  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` However thier is another error message, File "/Users/mac/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/webdriver_manager/driver.py", line 77
    self.auth_header = {'Authorization': f'token {self._os_token}'}
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Even I googled to solve this problem, there is no specific answers

Comment: often it means missing `)` in previous line. So it can be problem in previous line because line `self.auth_header = {'Authorization': f'token {self._os_token}'}` seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but it looks like the page you are trying to scrape has javascript which means BS won't do the job. When I simplify the code to return all of the soup it should return all of the html. So the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import re
import sys

URL = "https://www.douglascollege.ca/programs-courses/catalogue/programs"
r = requests.get(URL)
coverpage = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
print(soup)
```

produces

```
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr/><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>


</body></html>
```

That's why you aren't getting any `<a>`'s because there aren't any in the soup.

If the URL is changed to something else like:

```
URL = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gensim/gensim_creating_lda_mallet_model.htm"
```

The URL returns the page's html by calling the soup, and then there are `<a>`'s to get.

Viewing the source of the page you are trying to scrape turns up this line

```
<script src="/-/media/A1FA8497F6534B7D915442DEC3FA6541.ashx?636948345000000000"></script><script src="/-/media/ACA0B6DEC2124962B48341E8092B8B4D.ashx?636948345010000000"></script><script src="/-/media/68BA4C1C2A0D494F97E7CD7D5ECE72B0.ashx?637036665710000000"></script>
<!-- Javascripts goes between here -->
```

Along with several other mentions of javascript on the page. As discussed on in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744087/how-can-i-scrape-the-data-from-in-between-these-span-tags/62744938#62744938), you might try Selenium rather than BS. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) btw, in ur code, before request the url, you have to set the header to access the html :)